# Mix release not working on Phoenix live view demo app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I am toying with [Phoenix LiveView](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view) and I have setup an app with `mix phx.new demo --live --no-ecto`.

My primary objective is to create a release of this app, so then I can adapt it to what I need, but I am having trouble.

### Problem

In order to create a release for my demo app I followed the [Deploying with releases](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html) tutorial and changed all the necessary files.

Added the following to my `mix.exs`:

```
  def project do
    [
      app: :demo,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps(),
      releases: releases()
    ]
  end

  defp releases, do:
    [
      demo: [
        applications: [demo: :permanent]
      ]
    ]
```

And changed the files listed in Runtime Configurations properly as well:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#runtime-configuration

However, when I execute `_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/demo start` nothing happens. If I execute `_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/demo start_iex`  I get the following output:

```
$ _build/prod/rel/demo/bin/demo start_iex
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.11.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex>
```

Which leads me to believe something crashed.

When I visit `localhost:4000` it says the server is down.

### Question

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running with `iex -S mix phx.server` show any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The issue was in my original configuration file `config/config.exs`.

I had

```
# Configures the endpoint
config :demo, DemoWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  secret_key_base: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
  render_errors: [view: DemoWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json), layout: false],
  pubsub_server: Demo.PubSub,
  live_view: [signing_salt: "yRZCwQIF"]
```

Here I was missing the line:

```
# Configures the endpoint
config :demo, DemoWeb.Endpoint,
  server: true
```

So the full configuration should be:

```
# Configures the endpoint
config :demo, DemoWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  secret_key_base: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
  render_errors: [view: DemoWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json), layout: false],
  pubsub_server: Demo.PubSub,
  live_view: [signing_salt: "yRZCwQIF"],
  server: true
```

With this configuration now the server works.

Comment: This is documented in `config/prod.exs`. I'm aware it's not so easy to find. :)